# Converting a date in an invalid javascript format to an ics standard datetime field

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, calendar, icalendar

The date and time are actually separate in the data I have however I thought combining them would be the ideal solution?

The unaltered data looks like the following:
`2014/09/04` and `02:30PM`

```
var aDate = new Date('2014/09/04 02:30PM');
//Invalid date....
console.log(aDate.toString());
```

Needs to convert to the date that .ics files use which looks like:

`20140904T023000`  --> This is what the above date would turn into.

How do I do this?

[*JSBin you could test in...*](http://jsbin.com/soqosi/2/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var aDate = new Date('2014/09/04 02:30PM');
```

to

```
var aDate = new Date('2014/09/04 02:30 pm');
```

and it should work. You just need to put in a SPACE before PM. This will not give you invalid date error. Then you can use that date to get ICS format.

Here is the logic to get ICS format. I know this is not as efficient, but tried to keep it simple.

```
var pre = 
aDate.getFullYear().toString() +
((aDate.getMonth() + 1)<10? "0" + (aDate.getMonth() + 1).toString():(aDate.getMonth() + 1).toString()) + 
((aDate.getDate() + 1)<10? "0" + aDate.getDate().toString():aDate.getDate().toString());

var post = (aDate.getHours()%12).toString() + aDate.getMinutes().toString() + "00";

console.log(pre + "T" + post);
```

Comment: once you have converted it to date, that is a simple logic

Comment: Hey I placed an edit on your code. You used `getDay()` when you meant to use `getDate()`. Had me confused there :)

Comment: Also why did you do `%12` this also seems to make it incorrect.

Comment: getHours return hours in 24 hour notation (in chrome), I thought you wanted 2:30 pm represented as 230 and not 1430. you can fix that. getDay was typo btw getDate and getDay both return 4 in the date of your example, sorry for that

Comment: Yes I started in 12 hour notation however the ical format needs the 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to parse the date fine if you use 24 hour notation for time rather than denoting AM/PM.

From Chrome console:

```
(new Date('2014/09/04 02:30PM'));
Invalid Date
(new Date('2014/09/04 14:30'));
Thu Sep 04 2014 14:30:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

With this object, you should be able to construct the ICS format compliant date you require using the various getters on the Date prototype.

Answer (score 1):

There are no default api`s to convert to .ics file format, you can however do it manually.

```
function toITCFormat(date, time)
{
var timeCont = [],
dateCont = [];

if(time.toLowerCase().indexOf('pm')!=-1)
{

 timeCont = time.toLowerCase().replace('pm',00).split(':');   //assuming from your question seconds is never mentioned but only hh:mm i.e. hours and minutes
timeCont[0] = (parseInt(timeCont[0])+12)%24;
}
else
{
timeCont = time.toLowerCase().replace('am',00).split(':');
}
dateCont = date.split('/');

return dateCont.join('')+'T'+timeCont.join('');
}


var x = toITCFormat('2014/09/04','02:30PM');
console.log(x);// this will output ur .ics format
```

[*JSFiddle Example*](http://jsfiddle.net/Fogest/7ccdbbgg/1/)

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted. Just to add to your answer I linked to a jsfiddle in your answer.